# how to rewrite url via .htaccess

Tags: php, pdo

I want when someone view an ad for example https://clouditmarket.com.ng/ad/AD84772012 it should show clouditmarket.com.ng/Removal-of-Teath

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5bIW.jpg)

The question is how do i create url on my database and point to it on my code below and what is the right way to rewrite the .htaccess file to do this.

I really need your help because i understand that this will help me optimize my website ranking on google search engine.

Thank you all in advance.
//htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^ad/([^/.]+)/{0,1}$  ad_api.php?module=home&key=$1 [QSA,L]
```

THE AD INFO CODE

```
 $ad_id = $_GET['key'];
$shr = ''.$installation_path.'/ad/'.$ad_id.'';




try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_ads LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_ads.author = tbl_users.user_id WHERE tbl_ads.ad_id = :adid");
$stmt->bindParam(':adid', $ad_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$rec = count($result);

if ($rec == "1") {
    $not_found = "NO";
}else{
    $not_found = "YES";
    $title = "Not Found";

}

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $title = $row['title'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $adcond = $row['ad_condition'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $fixed = $row['fixed'];
        $brand = $row['brand'];
        $des = $row['description'];
        $post_date = $row['date_posted'];
        $short_des = $row['short_desc'];

        $author = $row['username'];
        $avatar = $row['avatar'];
        $verified = $row['verified'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $whatsappnum = $row['whatsapp_num'];

        $authid = $row['author'];
        $adstatus = $row['status'];
        

    }
                      
    }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Rename your question to "how to rewrite url via .htaccess". Better, search SO with the latter. This is duplicate question.